# Relation between Batch Size and Micro Batch Size

Tags: deep-learning, training, pytorch, large-language-models, gpu

In distributed training of large models (pipeline parallelism), a mini batch of training samples is divided into n-micro batches. Each device performs forward and backward passes for a micro batch.

What is the relation between Batch Size, Micro Batch Size, Gradient Accumulation (usually: batch size/micro batch size) in relation to no of GPUs as well as GPU size?

I understand that a micro-batch size is bounded by the GPU capacity, increasing it may lead to OOM error. Let suppose, for two GPU of 40GB capacity, we can use a max micro-batch size of 4 and we are using the batch size of 128. Next, we want to increase the count of GPU to 8 (each 40GB capacity). What is the best way to speed up. Whether increasing the batch-size will help? Or the global batch size has very subtle/no effect on the training time (only overhead is synchronization) in distributed training.